# OR expression in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have become incredibly confused over logical expressions in R. The following command gives me the expected result since 1 is equal to 1 or equal to 2:

```
> 1 == (1 | 2)
[1] TRUE
```

But on the other hand I get:

```
3 == (3 | 4)
[1] FALSE
```

If anybody could give some insight into what is happening here I would be very grateful!

Comment: You cant use `or` with numeric.. in first statement `1` interpent as `T` you can use `%in%` or (3 == 3 | 3== 4)

Comment: Try these in the console: `(3 | 4)`;`(1 | 2)`; `1 == TRUE`; `1 == (3 | 4)`; `0 == FALSE`; `3 == FALSE`; `3 == TRUE`, etc.

Comment: Just to expand on what @Batanichek said, `TRUE` and `FALSE` will be interpreted as 1 and 0, respectively, in a numeric context (e.g., try `as.numeric(c(FALSE,TRUE))` or `sum(c(TRUE, TRUE))`). For general logical operations with numbers, you can use `%in%` (e.g., `3 %in% c(3,4)`).

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The %in% function was indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the comments below your question for explanations. I guess what you really want to do is:

```
1 == 1 | 1 == 2
```

This is `TRUE` because the first test is `TRUE`.

```
3 == 3 & 3 == 4
```

This is `FALSE` because the second test is `FALSE` and `&` requires both (or all) tests to be `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question

> 1 == T

[1] TRUE

> 2==T

[1] FALSE